# Creating a Better Tabbed Interface in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, css, django

I've been trying to create a tabbed interface using Django. The current effort (which works fine) is having each template have the header hard-coded in, with the selected tab given the "selected" CSS attribute. Of course, this is a massive violation of DRY and I'm looking to remedy it.

My current idea is adding a jQuery script to the page that looks at all the tabs and sets one to "selected" if it's text matches the beginning of the title for the page. Is there a better way to do this without using JavaScript and just pure CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** The below link is broken now, however Django now has in built feature for comparing URLs now. Check [this bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18584) for more details.

You can create a template tag to implement it have a look at this http://gnuvince.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/a-django-template-tag-for-the-current-active-page/

You can implement something similar for your case.

Comment: The authors have deleted that site.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just pass in the selected tab in the context in each view that utilizes the tabs, and select the tab in a common header based on that value.